# Restrict input to single-level bullet list - jQuery optional

Tags: jquery, list, editor

I need an input mechanism to allow a user to create a single-level bullet list. I can't trust the user's ability to know HTML formatting or to not mess it up if auto-formated. I've been debating using a wysiwyg editor, but that doesn't force a bullet list.

I have jQuery installed, but can use other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list of input fields: http://jsfiddle.net/s3eAy/

Comment: I was going down that path, but then realized I'd need several buttons for sorting, or deleting one item higher than the last.

Comment: You would, but with today's tools, it is an easy job. This took about ten minutes and a few dozen lines of code: http://jsfiddle.net/s3eAy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could always try `contentEditable=true` if you dont need to support lower than IE8.

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VGvrL/2/)***

```
<ul contentEditable="true">
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <li>Test3</li>
    <li>Test4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. If I start with an empty UL, there are no <LI> elements, and therefore no starting bullets. Anyway around that?